# program doesn't see a file when launched in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I have this piece of code:

```
int main()
{
    string file = "stuff.jpg";

    Mat img = imread(file);
    if (img.empty())
    {
        printf("EMPTY");
        system("PAUSE");
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("display", img );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

When i launch this program in visual, i get that the img is empty, but if i run in from command line or by simply double clicking, it works fine. The path at the top when i run it in both visual and command line is the same. Why is that?

Comment: did you put the image in the debug directory?

Comment: Are you sure visual is running the program from the same location?

Comment: yes, it works if i double click to launch the program. It seems that visual takes the file from debug, and executes it in a different folder. Giving the absolute path works for both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The working directory when run from visual studio is controlled by the project properties:

```
Configuration Properties | Debugging | Working Directory
```

Set that appropriately or specify a full, absolute path instead of just `"stuff.jpg"` for the filename.

Comment: where is the $(ProjectDir) ? Isn't this the same place the debug executables are placed?

Comment: No. $(ProjectDir) is the folder containing the .vcproj file.

Comment: No - it's the directory the project file is in.  If you edit the property a dialog with a "Macros>>" button will display. When macros are enabled, the dialog will show the supported macro names and the value they would have at the moment.